# pass array to postgres in JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, common-table-expression

I want to do the following query in Postgres using JDBC:

```sql
with things as (values(1),(2)) select * from things;
```

So my Java code looks like this:

```java
String sql = "with things as (?) select * from things";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", new Integer[]{1, 2});
```

But this is throwing the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this using prepared statements in Java.  But, the bigger question is _why_ do you want to do this?  SQL is a language mainly geared towards extracting data from tables which _already_ exist, not really for populating them and then selecting from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you need using `unnest` like this:

```
Integer[] id = {1, 2};
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("int4", id);

try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
         "with things as (select unnest((?)::integer[])) select * from things")) {
    stmt.setArray(1, array);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    // use the result set
}
```